# Migrate data from Dynamics CRM 4.0 to 365

Tags: migration, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, data-migration

I have a client with an old CRM, Dynamics 4.0 on-premise and I want to migrate data from his CRM to a new instance Dynamics 365. Is there any way to migrate his data?

Answer (score 0):

Consider SSIS + KingsWaySoft adapter. Read the CRM 4.0 data directly from the SQL Server database using the standard SQL adapters.

Answer (score 0):

Moving from 4.0 to Dataverse is not easy... Its likely easier to migrate the data into a net new online instance after recreating the 4.0 datamodel and customizations...  Alternatively,you can always do in place upgrades up to a supported version to do a fast track migration with Microsoft help.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fasttrack/migration

Comment: It's not that simple: From the article you are referencing: _In order to perform the migration, your source environment must be a version of Dynamics CRM 2011, Dynamics CRM 2013, Dynamics CRM 2015, or Dynamics CRM 2016 (...)_ This is version 4.0 and OP's question is about _data_ migration.

Comment: 100% which is why I stated "You can always do in place upgrades up to a supported version"  Also I can see the confusion, I wanted to make two statements:  1) Its would be easier to migrate your date from 4.0 into a Dataverse, 2) if you really want to upgrade, you can try the fast track approach.  I've updated the response.